# Facing problem logging in to AWS ECR using GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github-actions, amazon-ecr

I have this workflow to automate deployment task:

```yaml
name: Deploy Application Docker Image to EC2 instance

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main
      
jobs:
  Continuous-Integration:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ****
          aws-secret-access-key: ****
          aws-region: ap-south-1

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: *****
          IMAGE_TAG: latest
        run: |
          docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .  
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
  Continuous-Deployment:
    needs: Continuous-Integration
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ****
          aws-secret-access-key: *****
          aws-region: ap-south-1

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Run Docker Image to serve users
        run: |
         docker run -d -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}" -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}" -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}" -e MONGODB_URL="${{ secrets.MONGODB_URL }}" -p 8080:8080 "${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}"/"${{ secrets.ECR_REPO }}":latest
```

this action `aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1` is working fine when I am using github hosted runner as in the job integration

But it is failing when using self-hosted runner as in the job deployment and got this error

```
Error: Could not login to registry ***.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com: WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/auth": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

can some one please help me figure out what is happening I am learning this for very first time.

Comment: [OpenID Connect](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/configuring-openid-connect-in-amazon-web-services) lets you authenticate with AWS, passwordless. Is anything preventing you from doing that?

Comment: Also, you're using very outdated version of all the actions (a common side effect of ChatGPT cutoff date, as I now recognize). You should update them all.

Comment: Also, I hope you're using secrets for key ID and access key, and not hardcode them in the workflow.

Comment: I don't know much about this, this code is provided to me in the online course which I am doing and yes I am using secrets, what I do not understand is that I able to login when using github hosted runner in Integration part but not when using self hosted runner in deployment

Comment: So the problem exists only on self-hosted runners? You don't mention that anywhere in the question.

Comment: Yes problem is in self hosted runner, sorry i missed that in question

Comment: But the workflow you show doesn't use a self-hosted runner, so it wouldn't result in the error you describe. You should [edit] the question.